# Referencing filetype from function

Tags: macvim, vim

I'm trying to write a function that acts on any filetype (thus is not a particular ftplugin), that has divergent behavior based upon what the filetype is. e.g.

```
 if (filetype=='objc')
     "do something
 elseif (filetype='cpp')
     "do something else
 endif
```

I read through the filetype docs, but nothing seems to reference this. Advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try accessing the option value:

```
if (&ft == 'objc')
   ...
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! For reference for other's, this feature is indeed (hidden) on the filetype vimhelp page.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html

Comment: Glad to help @Kurt. Haha, Vim help is really complete, that's the greatest thing and one of the problems too. There is a lot to read.

Comment: The `&option` syntax is documented under the help tag [`expr-option`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-option) in [`eval.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html) (which is also where `:if` is documented).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&` to access the value:

```
if ( &ft == 'cpp' )
    ...
```

etc.